# Possible for asp.net to be publisher for asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am currently developing a WCF publish subscribe service. Is it possible for the publisher to be a asp.net application connecting to the service ? As I cant seem to find any information online about vb code for WCF.

**EDIT** 
More details.

As my subscriber is a winform app, it is to subscribe to the WCF service using C# code and I am fine with that. the WCF Service is also coded in C# and I also have no problems with that. Normally the tutorials out in the web provides the code for a publisher to connect to the service and then call the publish code in console app or something. However all those is meant to be done in C#.

In my case, if i were to program the publisher code in a asp.net application. would it be possible?

**EDIT : Codes Added**

I am now currently using a C# mock publisher to post the data and the code are as follows

```
class Program : IPostingContractCallback
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InstanceContext site = new InstanceContext(new Program());
        PostingContractClient client = new PostingContractClient(site);

        client.PublishPost("testing");

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to shut down data source");
        Console.ReadLine();

        client.Close();
    }

    public void PostReceived(string postSampleData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PostChange(item {0})",postSampleData);
    }
}
```

and for my asp.net webpage, I want all this to happen when I call this line of code

```
ElseIf Request.QueryString("action") = "postAlert" Then
```

How do I write the code as stated in above for vb? and do I just do as what I do in a C# project? adding the app.config file and the generatedProxy.cs?

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on what you're trying to accomplish?  ASP.NET applications can connect to WCF services just fine.  Do you have any code that you've already tried and maybe have problems with?

Comment: Make sure your ASP.NET app has the System.ServiceModel dll added to its references (right-click on references in solution explorer, select Add Reference, navigate to System.ServiceModel and click OK).

Comment: okay! this part is solved. now for the main method...

Comment: post what you have for the main method (or what you think you should have) and I'll take a look and update my answer below accordingly.

Comment: what I should have for my main method for C# is just what I have posted on top. all those code runs when you press F5 or start debugging in Visual Studio. However for my asp.net webpage, there would be alot of if and else. I only want those code to run after the code "ElseIf Request.QueryString("action") = "postAlert" Then" Hence how should I code the above method into the codes after my elseif line?

Comment: I'm still a tad confused on what you're trying to do on this part.  I'm going to have to log off for now and get some sleep.  We can pick this up tomorrow.  You can e-mail me offline if you want (my e-mail address is in my profile).  I think we're pretty close to the solution now, though.

Comment: Thank you! I have managed to solve it myself. thanks for all your help! :D

Comment: excellent!  What was your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do ASP.NET with VB.NET, so it's not a case of VB vs C#.

You could very easily write an ASP.NET application and have it connect to the publish service.   The ASP.NET app would connect to the publishing service the same way a console app would (i.e., creating a new proxy/client and making calls to the service).

**Updated**

As Jon P said, use SVCUTIL and set the language to Visual Basic, like this:

```
SVCUTIL.EXE /language:vb (plus your other command line arguments)
```

[ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)

You'll want to add the `<serviceModel>` section to your Web.config, and generate the proxy in VB (using the /language:vb switch above).

Below is the VB version of the class you posted:

```
class Program Implements IPostingContractCallback

    Shared Sub Main(string[] args)

        Dim site As InstanceContext = New InstanceContext(New Program())
        Dim client AS PostingContractClient = New PostingContractClient(site)

        client.PublishPost("testing")

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to shut down data source")
        Console.ReadLine()

        client.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Sub PostReceived(ByVal postSampleData As String)

        Console.WriteLine("PostChange(item {0})", postSampleData)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Your ASP.NET app is acting as the publisher, but it's connecting to the publishing service (if I understand correctly), so all it's really doing is making a call to the service to publish the post.

The service itself should handle the callback and "publish" the event on the callback channel(s) for the subscriber.

So (without all the code for the various components I might be missing something - if I am, please let me know so I can update accordingly), all your ASP.NET app needs to do is:

```
Dim client As PostingContractClient = New PostingContractClient()
client.PublishPost("testing")
client.Close()
```

To reiterate (again, based on my understanding):

1. ASP.NET app calls the publishing service to publish the post.
2. The publishing service receives the post, and calls the callback method for all active subscribers.
3. Your subscribed client (the WinForm) receives the callback and processes it accordingly.

So for part 2, you might have something like:

```
public void PublishPost(string post)
{

    // Do something with the post

    callback.PostReceived(string postSampleData);

    // callback is a callback channel of type IPostingContractCallback
    // i.e:
    // IPostingContractCallback calback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPostingContractCallback>();
}
```

The client(s) should then pick up the PostReceived "event" and do what their implementation of the callback interface specifies.

Comment: thanks for your reply. is there any tutorial of examples out there of asp.net codes for connection to the publish service?

Comment: @Thomas - I'm not sure what  you mean.  The code (within .NET) to connect to a service is pretty much the same regardless of whether it's ASP.NET, WinForms, etc.  Is there a particular piece of code that's causing confusion?

Comment: as my project is a asp.net webpage. all the codes are in vb. so if I throw my generatedProxy file into the project, there seem to be some error? and i'm pretty new to the vb language hence I'm not sure how to type the codes for connecting to my WCF Publish service..

Comment: @Thomas - See my updated answer.  It's essentially the same as Jon P's answer, except it has an example of the language switch.

Comment: oh. thank you! after I did that, i generated the generatedProxy.cs.vb, i've added it to my project file and as in C#, I know that you have to import some libraries such as "using System.ServiceModel" etc etc. how and what should I do for my vb side as there are error of Type 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute' is not defined.

Comment: @Thomas - a quick way to add in missing using directives is to put the cursor over the class you're trying to use, and then hit ctrl-. (Control and period).  VS will supply a list of assemblies (usually only one) and you can then click on it in the context menu and it will add the using (Imports in VB) statement.  You may need to also add a reference to the assembly in the project.

Comment: the error correction options only provides me 3 choices, by changing it to something else. hmm.

Comment: Can you post your Imports statements from your .aspx.cs page?

Comment: Disregard my last (now deleted) comment.  Can you post the complete generated proxy code?  Since that's where the problem is occurring.

Comment: anyway, regarding the codes you have given on top, the way to implement a WCF publish code is the way i typed in c#, i have to extends to the IPostingContractCallBack method and then implementing the PostReceived class(even though i am just a publisher, i also have no idea why i need to implement that. lol) so for this case of vb, it can't possibly be i just paste the chunk of vb code after my 'ElseIf Request.QueryString("action") = "postAlert" Then' line?

Comment: Hmm....you can try posting the vb code after your `ElseIf` statement.  Note that Console.WriteLine() won't write output for you in your ASP.NET app.

Comment: i don think I am able to just post a class right in the middle of another class? sorry if i'm wrong. anw! thanks for all the help you have provided so far. and I can't straight away post the dim client part as i have to provide the instancecontext. And even if I use the class code outside of the class, there is 2 error, End of statement expected and keyword is not valid as identifier. the keyword is the word 'string' in the "string[] args"

Answer (score 1):

Use [svc utuil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) to create your proxy class and set the language flag to vb